# Como exatamente funciona o "private" e "protected" no Ruby?

Tags: ruby, private, protected

Estou estudando *Ruby* e cheguei na parte de controle de acesso. Eu já tinha estudado antes controle de acesso em *Java*, então eu pensava que seria o mesmo, mas para minha surpresa, a declaração `private` e `protected` são totalmente diferentes na linguagem *Ruby*.

A minha dúvida é, como exatamente o `private` e `protected` funcionam no *Ruby* e o porquê do *Ruby* não aceitar eu chamar um método privado utilizando `self` ?

```
class Teste

    def call_private
        self.private_method    # Se eu tirar o "self" ele funciona.
    end

    private

    def private_method
        puts "PRIVADO"
    end
end

teste = Teste.new
teste.call_private
```

Uma outra coisa que eu acabei de perceber, é que se eu definir meu método `call_private` depois do método `private_method`, o Ruby me informa que estou tentando chamar um método privado.

Isso significa que todos os método abaixo da declaração `private` são privados ? Se sim, existe alguma forma de se criar métodos públicos abaixo de métodos privados ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma para que possamos realizar o controle de acesso na linguagem Ruby <3 é, teoricamente, igual a todas as outras linguagens. Contudo, a sintaxe é um pouco diferente.

Todos os métodos, por *default*, são públicos, ou seja, ao declarar `private_method` o compilador do Ruby entender que esse método será publico.

```
class Teste

    def call_method
        self.private_method
    end

    def private_method
        "Private"
    end
end

t = Teste.new
puts t.call_method # Retorna Private
```

Já, se você desejar que ele seja privado, ai sim deveríamos usar a palavra reservada *Private* antes do métodos

```
class Teste

    private

    def call_method
        self.private_method
    end

    def private_method
        "Private"
    end
end

t = Teste.new
puts t.call_method # Nós retorna private method `call_method' called
```

Assim todos os métodos abaixo serão privados, que, nem nosso caso, nenhum podera ser invocado. 
Mas, se desejar voltar ao público, ai deveríamos redeclarar os mesmos como público da seguinte forma:

```
class Teste

    # Aqui podemos usar Public ou deixar sem, pois será público por Default
    def call_method
        private_method
    end

    private

    def private_method
        "Private"
    end
end

t = Teste.new
puts t.call_method
```